# Suggestions for building a treeview control in Android

Tags: android, listview, treeview, android-widget

Suggestions for building a treeview control in Android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) is probably the closest existing thing. Keep in mind though that it might be hard for a user to fat finger a tree view.

Answer (score 12):

I built a `treeview` of my own which supports n levels. It's easy to use in touch screens, especially on devices with larger screen.
I Used a class which extends `ListviewAdapter` and created my own `listitem`. the items know on which level they are and they inherit the `expandstate` of their parents (by remembering their own state). This Tree is quite fast up to thousand items.
[image]

Edit: added the code, but the way I wrote in the comment, It won't be very helpful, because it's very close to my own needs.

```
package de.supinfo.FISDroid;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.PaintDrawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Bitmap mIcon1;

private int active_view;
private int last_path;
public String[][] values = new String[0][];

public EfficientAdapter(Context context, String[][] str_arr_values, int int_active_view) {
    // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    values = str_arr_values;
    active_view = int_active_view;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    int padding = 0;

    // int selfstate = Integer.parseInt(values[position][4].trim());

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.xml.list_item_icon_text, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
        holder.expanded = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        holder.llout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon_text);
        holder.docs = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doc_count);
        holder.prun = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prun);
        holder.coord = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.coord);
        holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                main.tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
            }

        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
    String text = values[position][0];

    String docs = values[position][11];
    if (!docs.equals("0")) {
        // TODO
        // Anzeige das Dokumente vorhanden sind, eventuell Anzahl
        holder.docs.setText(docs);
        holder.docs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.docs.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    holder.coord.setVisibility(values[position][12].equals("") || values[position][12].equals("0") || values[position][12].equals("0.0") ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
    holder.prun.setVisibility(values[position][14].equals("") ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
    holder.text.setText(text);
    holder.text.setTextSize(GlobalVars.Style.TextSize);
    if (position == active_view) {
        holder.text.setTextColor(R.color.headline_font);
        PaintDrawable pd = new PaintDrawable(Color.RED);
        holder.llout.setBackgroundDrawable(pd);
        holder.text.setSingleLine(false);
        holder.button.setVisibility(values[position][1].equals("-1") ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.text.setTextColor(R.color.headline_font);

        PaintDrawable pd = new PaintDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.llout.setBackgroundDrawable(pd);
        holder.text.setSingleLine(true);
        holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    int i = Integer.parseInt(values[position][5].trim());
    mIcon1 = GlobalHelper.GetIcon(i);
    holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);

    if (values[position][8].equals("-1")) {
        holder.expanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.expanded.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
    } else if (values[position][8].equals("0")) {
        holder.expanded.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else if (values[position][8].equals("1")) {
        holder.expanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (values[position][9].equals("1")) {
            holder.expanded.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_revert);
        } else {
            holder.expanded.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
        }
    }
    padding = Integer.parseInt(values[position][7].trim()) * 24;
    convertView.setPadding(padding, 5, 5, 5);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout llout;
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
    ImageView expanded;
    ImageView coord;
    ImageView prun;
    TextView docs;
    Button button;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return values.length;
}

public String[] getValues(int position) {
    return values[position];
}

public String getValue(int position) {
    return values[position][0];
}

public String getDatid(int position) {
    return values[position][1];
}

public String getPath(int position) {
    return values[position][2];
}

public String getParent(int position) {
    return values[position][3];
}

public void set_active_view() {
    active_view = GlobalVars.cn.index;
}

public int get_active_view() {
    return active_view;
}

public void set_last_path(int position) {
    last_path = position;
}

public int get_last_path() {
    return last_path;
}

}
```

Edit: added the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/list_item_icon_text" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
android:background="@color/tree_normal_back" 
android:padding="1dip" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/plusminus" 
    android:layout_height="48dip" 
    android:layout_width="24dip" 
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
        android:layout_height="24dip" 
        android:layout_width="24dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
    android:layout_height="48dip" 
    android:layout_width="48dip" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    android:paddingLeft="4dip">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="48dip" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="16dip">

        <TextView 
            android:text="0" 
            android:id="@+id/doc_count" 
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/headline_font" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:textColor="@color/black" 
            android:textSize="12dip" 
            android:layout_margin="0dip" 
            android:padding="0dip" 
            android:paddingTop="0dip" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
            android:background="@drawable/ico_24_paperclip" 
            android:textStyle="normal" android:layout_height="16dip" android:layout_width="16dip">
        </TextView>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/prun" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:layout_height="16dip" 
            android:layout_width="16dip" android:background="@drawable/ico_24_prun"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/coord" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:layout_height="16dip" 
            android:layout_width="16dip"       android:background="@drawable/ico_24_coord"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/img_view" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:layout_height="24dip" 
            android:layout_width="24dip" />

</LinearLayout>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/tabs_edit"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:visibility="gone">
</Button>
<TextView 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:padding="2dip" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="22dip" 
    android:textColor="@color/tree_normal_font" 
    android:id="@+id/text_view" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice!  Would you care to share it?

Comment: -1 for boasting. It looks great but it's completely useless as an Answer, since you leave us completely on our own as to how to implement such a thing. All you're doing is showing off the fact that you found an answer, and you may as well have said "I can answer this" and left it at that.

Comment: sorry, but the code is very close to my needs, i wrote the basic thoughts how to solve the problem, the colde of the Adapter won't be very helpful...

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I've switched my -1 to a +. The code may be specific to your unique situation, but this way at least you've presented us with the foundation of a workable solution. :)

Comment: What does your "list_item_icon_text.xml" file look like?

Comment: Hello @2red13, the XML file has missing elements, could you please fix it ?

Comment: good answer but needed the full code if u have time send the link.

Comment: Can you provide us a full project? It would be helpful for so many people. thanks in anticipation.

Comment: you cannot answer with your ego turned on. You can have your ego turned off first before answering.

Comment: You shoud not comment with your brain turnend off. As i wrote at Dec 23 '11 at 9:35 , the code is very close to my needs, it would cost me a lot of time to make the stuff generic. with the provided informations you shoud be able to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that our company open-sourced as a library (so very easy to re-use):

http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

[image]

Comment: isn't is possible to do such tree without external libraries but with native android tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library: https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView to get your required tree-view. It's a N-level tree where you can control every single node in tree.

**Usage**

1) install: `compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'`

2) build tree-view:

```
 TreeNode root = TreeNode.root(); 
 TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("node-name");
 TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode("child-node-name-1");
 TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("child_node-name-2");

 parent.addChildren(child0, child1);
 root.addChild(parent);
```