# How can I make a view like this in android with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

Item and SubItem are called in DB and listed with recyclerview.
how can i make a horizontal and vertical line in front of items in dynamic ways. Or give me some keyword for googling.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMDu9.jpg)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271772/android-treeview

Comment: Check this java implementation(you will have to convert it I know): https://github.com/pi0/mangler/blob/master/android/src/org/mangler/android/ChannelList.java , it might be helpful