# How to create TreeView in android using vector?

Tags: android, treeview

I want to create a Tree view using vector in Android.It will like windows explorer i.e
If '+' is clicked then should expand sub folders.Like wise '-' should collapse Sub folders and files.I am developing small application.Please guide me if anyone knows.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several implementations of tree view, namely:
http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/
https://github.com/haxar/mangler/blob/master/android/src/org/mangler/android/ChannelList.java
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515080/200272

Kind regards,
Bo

Comment: Thank u for your quick reply Mr.Bo

Comment: Hi Bo I have Implemented fist link given by u.But in our company they are asking to do using Vector.

Comment: @sugan.s: Could you explain in detail what you mean by `Vector`? Did you mean: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html ?

Comment: Not like that Mr.Bo I am new to this java.In our company they asked to do Tree view I implemented using array list now they are asking to do in Vector.Please could u tell me what is the actual difference between Arraylist and vector.sorry if i asked silly

Comment: Checkout then a following link: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/08/java-best-practices-vector-arraylist.html (Note: If you solve your problem then accept answer so other people know what is most appropriate to solve the problem you faced).