# Adding TextView with padding depending on another TextView

Tags: java, android, binary-tree

As a beginner in Android, I'm trying to display a tree. I have already found how to add programmatically new TextViews but I don't know how to place them, I mean how to set their padding/margin depending on the father node.

Thanks a lot for your answers,

Baptiste

Comment: Set `padding/margin` to `parent` and then add `match_parent` for `height` and `width` to `child`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159758/suggestions-for-building-a-treeview-control-in-android

Comment: So should I use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

Dear first Use relative layout as parent and then add text view child.i did not add relative layout add relative layout as parent.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txttxt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="node"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txttxt12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txttxt1"
    android:text="Child"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txttxt1"/>
```

this is sample code i made for you. you can use according to your requirement.